# Photoshop on a retina screen, how to fix?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, retina

I am curious what's your favourite fix or option for using photoshop on a retina screen like a macbook pro 13' like mine.

I'm quite upset with this computer as it is a pain to do web design in, because as you may now, the photoshop canvas looks very very small at 100%.

For example a canvas of 1280x2000 px at 72dpi , is really small in photoshop (normal mode).
But if we select the low resolution mode, the fonts don't look crisp and I find myself scrolling all the time , left and right.

So for a person like me that is constantly working on 99designs, what should I do to fix this.
Besides connecting to an external display.
As my HP 23xi is not working with this macbook pro, don't ask me why, it gets cut and blurred.

Some help would be appreciated.

My Warmest Regards,

Luís Fernandes

Comment: It sounds like you may have triggered OSX's zoom mode. I'm not entirely clear what the issue you are having is. Normally, Photoshop should run on a retina display the same as on a non-retina display.

Comment: I can see you haven't tried a retina screen. Photoshop runs exactly the same, but the size of the canvas it's much much smaller when at 100%. There are alot of people with the same question as I do. Thanks alot mate for answering ;)

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you are saying. the artwork at 100% ('actual size') is small. Yea, to fix that, you want to probably view your work at 200% (which is 100% on non-retina screens).

Comment: Yeah, but that's the worst option, since everything gets low-res

Comment: It's not low-res. Just zoomed in on your particular screen. When working in a raster tool, you're typically zooming in and out all the time anyways. I suggest zooming in to 200% as needed to view it 'roughly how it will look size-wise' but also check at 100% to get the pixel-for-pixel view.

Comment: Alternatively, since it sounds like you are making logo, consider switching to a vector tool like Illustrator. Logos typically should be made as vectors whenever they can, and also don't have this issue of zooming pixels.

Comment: By the way, any image at 200% on a retina screen looks exactly the same as it does at 100% on a non-retina screen. This is because the resolution of the image isn't any different even though the pixel density of the screen is twice as much.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I wish pixels in retina photoshop would act like in retina web browser: saying gimme something worth 100px actually creates 200 "retina pixels" and 100 non retina ones.

Comment: Close Photoshop. Right-click on the Photoshop.app, choose Get Info. Tick "Open in Low Resolution". Re-open Photoshop and your document.

Comment: I agree with OP - DA01 you mustn't design in Photoshop on a Mac with a retina display.  This is a real issue and Adobe are ignoring it. See here http://designm.ag/photoshop-2/pixel-design-issue-photoshop-retina/

Answer (score -1):

It also depends what target devices you're designing for; if you're going for mobile, designing on retina for retina is fine, if you're targeting desktop browsers, you need to zoom in, even if using [command+mouse wheel] zoom.

You can also try validating your Photoshop file for device-specific compatibility and other web-specific issues via https://www.oss-usa.com/web-preflight

Comment: Browsers don't display things the same way was Photoshop does on a Retina screen... even on mobile devices and Retina screens.